# What is the Radius of Convergene of $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{4^n}z^{2n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation, power-series

Here's what I have:

$f(z) = z + \frac14z^3+\frac1{4^2}z^5+...$

So, my coefficients are either $0$ or $\frac1{4^n}$ with $\frac1{4^n}$ being the supremum.

So, $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} |c_n|^{\frac1n}$, where $c_n$ is the sequence of coefficients, gives me $\frac1{4^n}^{\frac1n} = \frac14$

Therefore, radius of convergence = $4$.

But when I check WolframAlpha to verify my answer I get $2$:
[Wolfram Alpha Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=radius+convergence+sum&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SumConvergence%22%2C+%22sumconvergencefunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%284%5En%29z%5E%282n%2B1%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SumConvergence%22%2C+%22sumconvergencevariable%22%7D+-%3E%22n%22)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $c_n$ in your convergence test refers to the coefficient of $z^n$, not $z^{2n+1}$...

Comment: @Sharkos: Yes, but wouldn't the limsup of those coefficients still be $\frac14$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence of the series for $f(\sqrt{z})$ is $4$, so the radius of convergence for $f(z)$ is $\sqrt{4} = 2$.

Or you could see that $c_n \not =\frac{1}{4^n}$. Instead, $c_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{4^n}$, so the radius of convergence is $$\frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{4^n}\right|^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2$$

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to consider the series $\sum_n\frac{z^{2n}}{4^n}$. By first principles (for example the root test for absolute convergence of series)
The series converges for all $z$ such that
$$
\lim_n\sqrt[n]{4^{-n}z^{2n}}=\frac{1}{4}|z|^2<1$$

That is, the series converges for all $z$ such that $|z|<2$.

---

Once can also calculate the radius of convergence form directly from the formula
$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_m\sqrt[m]{|a_m|}}$$
Rewrite
$$\sum_n\frac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}}=\sum_ma_mz^m$$
where $a_m=0$ if $m$ is odd and $a_m=2^{-m}$ if $m$ is even. Then
$\limsup_m\sqrt[m]{|a_m|}=2^{-1}$ and so, $R=2$.